# Python JSON to MYSQL - Dynamically

Tags: python, mysql, json

Based on my reading on here and other sites it appears as though in order to get every KV pair from json into mysql you need to actually specify every key name. Is there no way to do this more dynamically? ie just take my entire json and put it into mysql creating whatever columns are needed? or at least and initial given this json here's the columns that will be created?

```
for key,value in json_data.items():
    print key+"=>"+val
```

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, columns aren't created by inserting data. The columns must exist in the table *before* you insert.

So you could write code in your app to analyze your JSON, get a list of all the keys, and run a CREATE TABLE to define a table with a column corresponding to each key (I hope your JSON is just an object one-level deep, and not a more complex JSON document with nested objects, arrays, etc.).

Then your app would read the JSON a second time, this time inserting data to the table, putting values in the columns corresponding to your JSON keys.

Comment: seems like in order to get a list of keys you need to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930051/how-can-i-ask-for-a-key-of-a-subkey-in-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: Why not just use `json_data.keys()`?